# Unable to connect to localhost Apache Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp, localhost

I run xampp (apache) on Ubuntu 12.04. I've got localhost declared as ServerName localhost in httpd.conf. So far, I've not experienced problems with this but now, the browser Firefox is unable to connect to localhost. What could  the problem be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found the answer and responding to myself in case it could be of interest to others; Actually, Apache server was not running. When I started xampp, it said Apache is already running but in fact wasn't due to the fact that the file logs/http.pid was corrupt. I deleted this file and then restarted xampp. This time it did launch the apache server and everything is fine.